# Django. Authentication (user returns None)

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'm trying to make sign in form using Django.
So I created a function in views and it looks like this:

```
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SigninForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            login = request.POST.get('login', '')
            password = request.POST.get('password', '')
            user = auth.authenticate(username=login, password=password)
            print(user)
            if user is not None and user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponse("OK")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("ERROR")
    else:
        form = SigninForm()     
    return render(request, 'signin.html', {'form': form})
```

and it works (prints `OK` and `print(user)` returns the name of the user), but only for the user I created when I did `syncdb` (superuser).

however when I try to create users like this:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignupForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignupForm()
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

it prints `ERROR` when I try to sign in, and `print(user)` returns `None`

P.S.

- I added: `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend', )` in my `settings.py`
- and I can see users created by signup function in my admin page (it looks just like the superuser)

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. 
Will you please help me?

Comment: Ok, I got it..
Just created user like this: user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['login'], password=request.POST['password'])

Answer (score 0):

When you use create_user function as

> User.objects.create_user(username='username', password='password')

, You do not need to do password encrypt before.

It would be made auto.